# How do I add more fields to share wishlist in magento?

Tags: php, forms, magento

Im altering my share a wishlist form in Magento 1.9, I've found the form for my wishlist which is basically an email address box and a message box, iv removed the email box and put a hidden input form to only send the wishlist to one address that works now Im trying to add name, address, phone number, postcode etc to the form but having no look, I would try and find the script that processes the form that sends the email but the action is getSendURL() ?> so not very helpful Ive tried altering the textarea message with inputs with the id of message but no luck any ideas on how to accomplish this ?

```
<div class="page-title">
<h1><?php echo $this->__('Share Your Wishlist') ?></h1>
</div>
<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
<form action="<?php echo $this->getSendUrl() ?>" id="form-validate" method="post">
<div class="fieldset">
    <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
    <h2 class="legend"><?php echo $this->__('Sharing Information') ?></h2>
    <ul class="form-list">
        <li class="wide">

            <div class="input-box">
                <input type="hidden" name="emails" id="email_address" value="sample@gmail.com"/>
                <!--<textarea name="emails" cols="60" rows="5" id="email_address" class="validate-emails required-entry"><?php echo $this->getEnteredData('emails') ?></textarea>/-->
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="wide">
            <label for="message"><?php echo $this->__('Message') ?></label>
            <div class="input-box">
                <textarea id="message" name="message" cols="60" rows="5"><?php echo $this->getEnteredData('message') ?></textarea>
            </div>
        </li>
        <?php if($this->helper('wishlist')->isRssAllow()): ?>
        <li class="control">
            <div class="input-box">
                <input type="checkbox" name="rss_url" id="rss_url" value="1" title="<?php echo $this->__('Check this checkbox if you want to add a link to an rss feed to your wishlist.') ?>" class="checkbox" />
            </div>
            <label for="rss_url"><?php echo $this->__('Check this checkbox if you want to add a link to an rss feed to your wishlist.') ?></label>
        </li>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="buttons-set form-buttons">
    <p class="required"><?php echo $this->__('* Required Fields') ?></p>
    <p class="back-link"><a href="<?php echo $this->getBackUrl(); ?>"><small>&laquo; </small><?php echo $this->__('Back')?></a></p>
    <button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Share Wishlist') ?>" class="button"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Share Wishlist') ?></span></span></button>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive figured it out how to add additional fields to your wishlist form you need to goto your IndexController.php which is located at app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/controllers/IndexController.php goto line 627 should be a variable

```
$message = nl2br(htmlspecialchars((string) $this->getRequest()->getPost('message')));
```

underneath that add the varibles that you have added to your wishlist form like name address etc.

```
$title =            $_POST['title'];
$first_name =       $_POST['first_name'];
$surname =          $_POST['surname'];
$email2 =           $_POST['email'];
$phone =            $_POST['phone'];
$housenamenumber =  $_POST['housenamenumber'];
$streetname =       $_POST['streetname'];
$city =             $_POST['city'];
$postcode =         $_POST['postcode'];
```

and then once youve added them goto line 690 and find

```
array(
                    'customer'       => $customer,
                    'salable'        => $wishlist->isSalable() ? 'yes' : '',
                    'items'          => $wishlistBlock,
                    'addAllLink'     => Mage::getUrl('*/shared/allcart', array('code' => $sharingCode)),
                    'viewOnSiteLink' => Mage::getUrl('*/shared/index', array('code' => $sharingCode)),
                    'message'        => $message,
                    'title'          => $title,
                    'firstname'      => $first_name,
                    'surname'        => $surname,
                    'email2'         => $email2,
                    'phone'          => $phone,
                    'housenamenumber'=> $housenamenumber,
                    'streetname'     => $streetname,
                    'city'           => $city,
                    'postcode'       => $postcode,


                )
```

and adjust them accordingly, after that alter your email template and add {{var firstname}} etc presto it works any questions please don't hesitate to ask.